# Generalized Linear Model in SPSS, with dummy-coded predictors

Tags: regression, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, unbalanced-classes, poisson-regression

I'm struggling with the interpretation of some data. A quick overview of my study. I have data from 48 different US Universities on the amount of substance use-related activity discussed on anonymous social media (coded SUDS_count). I would like to do some linear modeling to see how much Region, Locale, Control, and Size of university predicts the overall count. There are 8 regions, whereas the other variables are dichotomous (Locale= Rural vs. Urban; Control = Private vs Public; and Size = Not large vs. Large; each coded 0, 1, respectively).

I had SPSS run the generalized linear model prompt, using a Poisson with Log Link distribution, since my data are count data.
Where I'm struggling is with the interpretation of the "redundant parameters".
I also had SPSS auto-create dummy variables for region (called RegDum1-8)

My output is as follows, with beta weights reported:

Intercept    4.347

RegDum1=0    .142

RegDum1=1    0a

RegDum2=0    .088

RegDum2=1    0a

....
.... (and so on)

RegDum8=0    0a

RegDum8=1    0a

Locale=0    -.136

Locale=1     0a

You get the point. I'm struggling with the 8 regions, and specifically, Region 8, where both beta weights are 0. The "a" indicates that it is "set to zero because this parameter is redundant."

I have read elsewhere that one can interpret the intercept for this redundant parameter, but this doesn't seem to make sense with the data, because it suggests that region 8 is a very powerful predictor (which it is not).

Instead, I believe that each of the other 7 regions are being compared to region 8 (i.e. region 8 is the contrast variable), but I don't know how to interpet these numbers if that is the case because Region 8 is an illogical comparison (i.e. it is not intended to be a control).

I am sure something weird is happening because I have so many dummy variables, but I don't know how to interpret them.

p.s. in reality, a lot of this is not going to matter, because Region does not appear to have any statistically significant effect overall. However, I still would like to know how to interpet.

p.p.s There are unequal sample sizes within the regions. Region 5, for example, has 10 universities, while region 3 (the smallest) has only 4. The design was originally balanced in data collection, but a number of universities in each region did not meet full criteria (e.g. in many regions, there are no rural, public, large universities).

Comment: The intercept in a generalised linear model is seldom of scientific interest. Here it is estimating the count in the cell with all categorical predictors at their reference value.

Comment: Right. Thank you. and as you said, I am not particularly interested in the intercept here, except that it is capturing some of the variance in Region 8, because Region 8 is being used as a reference value. However, I think it is also capturing all the other reference values too, so I cannot just interpret the intercept as Region 8, because I have several predictors, correct? Thus, where can I find the value for Region 8?